# commutative square up to sign, Poincaré duality

Tags: algebraic-topology, poincare-duality

Let $M$ be smooth oriented manifold with boundary $\partial M $, dim$M=n$. The two short exact sequences in de Rham cohomology and singular homology

$$0\longrightarrow{}\Omega^{}(M, \partial M)\xrightarrow{\ j_{} \ }\Omega^{}(M)\xrightarrow{\ i^{} \ }\Omega^{*}(\partial M )\xrightarrow{\  \ }0$$ and 
$$0\longrightarrow{}C_{}(\partial M )\xrightarrow{\ i_{} \ }C_{}(M)\xrightarrow{\ j_{} \ }C_{*}(M, \partial M)\xrightarrow{\  \ }0$$
induce these long exact sequence in cohomology de Rham and singular homology $$\cdots \longrightarrow{}H^{n-k}_{dR}(M)\xrightarrow{\ i^{*} \ }H^{n-k}_{dR}(\partial M )\xrightarrow{\ \delta \ }H^{k+1}_{dR}(M,\partial M)\xrightarrow{\ j_{*} \ }H^{k+1}_{dR}(M)\longrightarrow\cdots$$\

$$\cdots \longrightarrow{}H_{k}(M, \partial M)\xrightarrow{\ \partial \ }H_{k-1}(\partial M)\xrightarrow{\ i_{*} \ }H_{k-1}({M})\xrightarrow{\ j_{*} \ }H_{k-1}(M, \partial M)\longrightarrow\cdots$$

We define the the map $I_{M} : H^{n-k}(M, \partial M)\rightarrow  H_{k}(M), \ \ [M]\frown\omega$, where [M] fundamental class M.

$I_{\partial M} : H^{n-k}(\partial M)\rightarrow  H_{k}(\partial M), \ \ \partial[M]\frown\omega$, where $\partial [M]$ fundamental class $\partial M$.

How to prove that $ i_{*}\circ I_{\partial M}$ and $I_{M}\circ \delta$ commute up to signe $(-1)^{n-k+1}$ ?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: \item Let $\omega \in \Omega^{n-k}(\partial M) : d\omega = 0$. Therefore it exists $\omega^{\prime} \in \Omega^{n-k}(M)  : i^{*}(\omega^{\prime}) = \omega\ \text{и}\ \ \delta\left[\omega\right] = \left[d\omega^{\prime}\right]$. In one hand, we have

Comment: \begin{equation*} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
I_{M}(\delta(\omega)) & = \left[M\right]\frown \delta(\omega)\\
& = \left[M\right]\frown d\omega^{\prime}\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Since  $i_{*}$ is a inclusion, we have

Comment: \begin{equation*} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
i_{*}(I_{\partial M}(\omega)) & = I_{\partial M}(\omega)\\
& = \partial\left[M\right]\frown\omega\\
& = (-1)^{n-k}\partial\left(\left[M\right]\frown\omega^{\prime}\right) \ \ \text{в класс когомологиях}\ \ H_{k-1}\left(M\right).\\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Comment: On the other hand,
\begin{equation}
\partial\left(\left[M\right]\frown\omega^{\prime}\right)=(-1)^{n-k}\left(\partial\left[M\right]\frown\omega - \left[M\right]\frown d\omega^{\prime}\right)
\end{equation}
and since $\omega$ -- closed form, then
\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
 \partial\left[M\right]\frown \omega = (-1)^{n-k}\partial(\left[M\right]\frown\omega),
\end{equation}

Comment: where $\partial(\left[M\right]\frown\omega)$ -- cycl. If we put  $(12)$ in $(11)$, we'd have
$$\left[M\right]\frown d\omega^{\prime} = (-1)^{n-k+1}\partial\left(\left[M\right]\frown\omega^{\prime}\right) + \partial\left(\left[M\right]\frown \omega\right)$$
Therefore in the homology class  $H_{k-1}(M)$ we have
\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\left[M\right]\frown d\omega^{\prime} = (-1)^{n-k+1}\partial\left(\left[M\right]\frown\omega^{\prime}\right).
\end{equation}